# React js material ui Grid responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, grid, material-ui

[image]

As you can see from the image on the left I have a map with the controls, on the right I have a series of fields (last update, a table and an input field).

What I would like to do is that when it reaches a certain size (`device` example) the right side goes down under the map, the map then takes all the available space.

As you can see from the image when you resize a part of the table you do not see, you have to scroll.

Can you give me a hand?

In the original project I also use:

```
        "tailwindcss": "1.2.0",
        "tailwindcss-dir": "4.0.0"
```

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-m8lsx?file=/demo.js)

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {
  Grid,
  TextField,
  Paper,
  Typography,
  Tooltip,
  Chip
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { red, teal } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import Map from "./Map";
import ToggleButtonMap from "./ToggleButtonMap";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import "./styles.css";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {},
  paper: {
    display: "flex",
    border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    padding: 10
  },
  control: {}
}));

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    historyParking: [
      {
        idPs: "7ff2-4e5d-b164-661b511e609e-1",
        free: false,
        latitude: 33,
        longitude: 10,
        timeCurrent: "23/10/2020 15:13:23"
      },
      {
        idPs: "7ff2-4e5d-b164-661b511e609e-1",
        free: true,
        latitude: 33,
        longitude: 10,
        timeCurrent: "23/10/2020 15:13:23"
      }
    ]
  });
  const { historyParking } = state;
  const classes = useStyles();

  const columns = [
    {
      name: "Name",
      selector: "idPs",
      cell: ({ idPs }) => (
        <Tooltip title={`${idPs}`} placement="right-start" arrow>
          <span>{shortCode(camPlace(idPs).idPs)}</span>
        </Tooltip>
      )
    },
    {
      name: "Place",
      selector: "idPs",
      cell: ({ idPs }) => camPlace(idPs).place
    },
    {
      name: "Status",
      selector: "free",
      cell: ({ free }) => (
        <div>
          <Chip
            variant="outlined"
            style={{
              color: free ? teal["600"] : red["600"],
              borderColor: free ? teal["600"] : red["600"]
            }}
            label={`${fixName(free?.toString())}`}
            size="small"
          />
        </div>
      )
    },
    {
      name: "Last update",
      selector: "timeCurrent",
      cell: ({ timeCurrent }) => (
        <Tooltip title={`${timeCurrent}`} placement="right-start" arrow>
          <span>{timeCurrent}</span>
        </Tooltip>
      )
    }
  ];

  const shortCode = (code, left = 10, right = 10) => {
    return `${code.substring(0, left)}...${code.substring(
      code.length - right,
      code.length
    )}`;
  };

  const fixName = (name) => {
    return name
      ?.replace("_", " ")
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(" ")
      .map((word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
      .join(" ");
  };

  const camPlace = (a) => {
    const idPs = a.split("-");
    const place = idPs.pop();
    return { idPs: idPs.join("-"), place };
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Paper elevation={1} className={classes.paper}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item>
                <ToggleButtonMap />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} className="h-512">
                <Map />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Grid container direction="column" spacing={1}>
            <Grid item>
              <TextField
                id="city_zone"
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
              ></TextField>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Typography component="div">
                Last update: 23/10/2020 16:31:35
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <div
                style={{
                  border: "1px solid #dadce0",
                  backgroundColor: "#fff",
                  marginTop: 5
                }}
              >
                <DataTable
                  title={"History"}
                  columns={columns}
                  data={historyParking}
                  highlightOnHover
                  defaultSortField="timeCurrent"
                  defaultSortAsc={false}
                  pagination
                  paginationPerPage={6}
                />
              </div>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for

```
    <Grid item xs={8} sm={12}>
      <Paper elevation={1} className={classes.paper}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item>
            <ToggleButtonMap />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} className="h-512">
            <Map />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What can I be the other ways?
Because it seems my problem is starting from a specific size <1540, it gives me problems.
So it seems to be a problem between lg and xl.
In your opinion this part is right:
``
               <Grid item xs = {12} sm = {12} className = "h-512">
``
Could this be the problem?

Comment: `<Grid item xs={8} sm={12}>`  at maps container and `<Grid item xs={12} className="h-512">` for map will sove this

Comment: You say this: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-e47vt?file=/demo.js
It doesn't seem to work very well.